# Rig for a window that opens from above

Tags: rigging

So, I'm working on this window project, but I'm new to rigging. I've searched on youtube for tutorials, but there seem to be no tutorial for this kind of rig. So, can anyone tell me how to create rig for this window, and explain me how it works.

I need rig that makes window move between these two positions.

[image: Image of an open window]

[image: image of a closed window]

I would be very thankful. Cheers!

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78170/precise-mechanical-rigging-intuitive-method/78183#78183