# Setting up mechanical linkage of levers

Tags: animation, rigging

Since I'm new to Blender (I made the model and rigging with gMax), I find myself stuck trying to set up a linkage for the reverser of my steam locomotive. I was finally able to set the pivot point for the lifting arm using the iv constraint (reverser 1a).

[image: Reverser 1a]

When attempting the function the arm moved correctly but the bones disconnected and failed to raise the reverser arm. None of the constraints could remedy this (reverser 1b).

[image: reverser 1b]

Further attempts kept the bones together.

[image: reverser 2a]

However I was never able to keep the last bone attached to the linkage.

[image: reverser 2b]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Have a great day.
TOM

Addendum:
I have been able to answer most of my questions through a lot of trial and error. I am trying to model this steam locomotive for use in TRAINZ.

[image: lok]

[A short video of my progress can be seen on Youtube.](https://youtu.be/49Yn-D2hLMc)

I was able to do the linkage with an armature starting at the reverser lever. Using IK constraints with limited chain length I could connect to various objects. Everything works great when running forward:

[image: forwards]

The problem is when shifting into reverse since the radius and valve rods are location constrained to the Y-axis of the expansion links pivot point, the motion is no longer correct.

[image: reverse]

I have tried everything I could think of, including the clamp to constraint, without success. I would be grateful for any ideas. Have a great day. TOM

Comment: Do you specifically need bones for this? Have you tried with a constraints only solution? Might be easier to achieve what you want. See related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78170/precise-mechanical-rigging-intuitive-method/78183#78183

Comment: Sorry. Just got the notification of your reply. Thanks for the link. I tried using rigid body hinges but wasn't successful. Thanks again. TOM

Comment: Here one of my attempts. I believe I set up the hinge correctly. The L-shaped arm is child of the lever base and can rotate on the x-axis which is the z-axis for the hinge. (image 1).

Comment: Here one of my attempts. I believe I set up the hinge correctly. The L-shaped arm is child of the lever base and can rotate on the x-axis which is the z-axis for the hinge. (image 1) On the second picture you see that rotation of the l-shaped arm breaks apart the objects instead of bending at the hinge. I may try bones again. TOM   P.S. Could not add pictures. control G failed to work.

Comment: Could you include the name of the locomotive?

Answer (score 2):

I've been at it over a month. I have a 99% solution.
The pictures show what I have done in Forward and Backward gear.
The solution isn't perfect because the travel between gears is on a circular route. I posted a video on Youtube. The first 30 seconds are still photos and then the action starts. If anyone has an idea how to make a straight route let me know. Thanks. Have a great day. 
TOM

https://youtu.be/L5k6kLqcca4

[image: FORWARD]

[image: BACKWARD]