# array modifier with object offset is not working properly

Tags: modifiers

I was trying to create Otto Octavius's robot arms and I have made the arm parts and I have trouble making the claws part

I should mention I am using blender. version 2.93.5.

I was trying to use the array modifiers with object offset for 1 claw with respect to the, you know, the prism and I get the following result but I want to get the 2nd image.

What I wanted was in the second image if I open 1 claw others should open up also and vise versa.

[image]

[image]

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1MfwF4SBJIx4n1x-SCapsmaiPBOTusC9y?usp=sharing

Comment: assuming you are following the polyfjord tutorial...either provide your blend file or restart the tutorial from the start. The tutorial is really good explained and try to do it exactly as Polyfjord does. Each step. E.g. if he scales in edit mode, scale in edit mode, NOT in object mode. Makes a huge difference. I made this mistake often as beginner because i didn't know the difference.

Comment: you are showing an armature, don't you want to control the action with the armature rather than with an Array modifier? Array modifier is rather made for modelling. Also maybe shar eyour file (upload and copy paste the URL): https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Maybe [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/180276/35559) is relevant .. no array, though..

Comment: @Chris yes I was using polyfjord's tutorial but I was doing it action for action and it still gave the weird copies

Comment: ok, then please provide blend file, so we can help you.

Comment: idk how to provide the file so I just gonna give drive link

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1MfwF4SBJIx4n1x-SCapsmaiPBOTusC9y?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Array modifier works as expected. Your offset object (*Circle*) has scale less than claw, so each copy of the object smaller than the previous one. Your offset object (*Circle*) rotation is in X axis instead of Y, so each copy rotates in X axis instead of Y. Take a look at transform values that you have:

[image]

So fix that - select all objects and press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>,  <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>,  <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> to clear all mess that you have. Then select object *Circle* and rotate it at 120 deg around Y: <kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>Y</kbd>, 120. You will end up here:

[image]

Now you can return *Circle* at original position, but in **Edit Mode**

Also, consider using Empties as an offset object instead of geometry that you are already using, because you can rotate and scale empties, without affecting exsisting geometry.

Comment: Crantisz I didn't exactly understand
Could you please explain like idk you will explain to a noob
you know cause I am one
I meant about the first part I got the thing about the empties but not the first part

Comment: Thing about the empties is optional. Just keep in mind, that usually people use empties for such tasks.

Comment: Thank you @Crantisz 
I used and empty to object offset it so that worked an every thing is working smoothly.

Comment: I tried the rotation thing but it didn't work but thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the size of the empty and adjusting the size of the duplicate object with the original object.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial, stand on their own, and thoroughly explain the solution and procedure. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can [edit] your post and provide some more details about the workflow and how it works, feel free to restore it, otherwise it may be converted to a comment. Perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating some steps and final result. See [How to write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)